# Problem to use GWT client to call a Restlet web service

Tags: gwt, restlet

I am using Restlet framework, and I want to use GWT as the client side. I have already created some ServerResources in Restlet. Here is the codes for the GWT client:

BookResourceProxy.java

public interface BookResourceProxy extends ClientProxy
{
  @Get
  public void getBooks(Result callback);
}

The class that use this Proxy:

```
BookResourceProxy wrp = GWT.create(BookResourceProxy.class);

wrp.getClientResource().setReference("/Books");

wrp.getClientResource().getClientInfo().getAcceptedMediaTypes().add(new
Preference<MediaType>(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));


wrp.getBooks(new Result<String>() 
    {
  public void onFailure(Throwable caught) 
  {
    Window.alert("Fail" + caught.getMessage());
  }

  public void onSuccess(String json) 
  {
    Window.alert(json);
  }
});
```

When I run the application, I always receive the error:

"No source code is available for type org.restlet.resource.ClientProxy; did you forget to inherit a required module?"

But if I inherit it in the .gwt.xml:

Another error occurs:

Unable to find 'org/restlet/Restlet.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
      [ERROR] Line 13: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'

Does anybody know why?

Thanks in advance!

Ike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the [GWT edition of Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/downloads/2.0/restlet-gwt-2.0.5.zip) and that `org.restlet.jar` is in the GWT compiler's classpath.

Answer (score 0):

In GWT side you'll have to use package `org.restlet.client.*`, on GAE side you use `org.reslet`.